# how to get BitTorrent client in tails os

Tags: tails, bittorrent

i know tails purpose is different but for usb live session i cant find anything better and simple than tails. is there anyway to get BitTorrent client in it like transmission and i don't mind compromising anonymity, i just use it like any other os

Answer (score 0):

Welcome jack.

You will need to install a additional software, a VPN one whose allows torrent applications. No more to say, just paid one will allow you to use applications that uses torrent protocol. To doesn't allow torrent by two reasons: they are such bandwidth consuming and the second is that tor uses only complete TCPs connections, while torrent protocol uses UDP a lot, mainly to find peers/nodes

Answer (score 0):

Tails does not ship any BitTorrent software and is unlikely to do so in the future.

The problem with using BitTorrent over Tor is double:

- It harms the network, [as stated by suomynona](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/31031/suomynona). See: https://blog.torproject.org/why-tor-slow-and-what-were-going-do-about-it.
- It is technically [hard to do it properly](https://blog.torproject.org/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea) and ***will probably break your anonymity***.

There are relatively [vague plans to improve on this situation](https://blog.torproject.org/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea).

See the [Tails' FAQ on Bittorent](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/#bittorrent)